# Expanding Tableview sections . Issue with checking if section is expanded or not

Tags: arrays, swift, computed-properties

Im basically trying to make an expandable UITableview I have two different data models (add posts ) and (reviewPosts) I created a struct to house the two, then I am using a computed property to return me the two models so as to I can feed my tableview array. I have all the logic set up to hide and show sections however when it comes to setting the variable isExpanded I cannot because my computed var is read only. Im unsure how to set the newValue (bool).

```
  // class for constructing tableview data

class FeedConstructor {
    public static var feedPosts: [ExpandableItem] {
           var isOpen = true

            return [ExpandableItem(isExpanded: isOpen, items: posts), 
            ExpandableItem(isExpanded: isOpen, items: reviews)]      
         }

    static var posts = [AddPost]()
    static var reviews = [ReviewPost]()

   }


  // here I am trying to set the isExpanded property
  class ViewController: UIViewController {
     func dropDownPressed(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let section = sender.view?.tag else {return}


        var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
        for row in FeedConstructor.feedPosts[section].items.indices{
            print(section,row)
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
            indexPaths.append(indexPath)
        }

    // I cant set this property because its get only.. 
       let isExpanded = FeedConstructor.feedPosts[section].isExpanded
        FeedConstructor.feedPosts[section].isExpanded = !isExpanded!

        if isExpanded! {
            tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
        } else {
            tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)

        } 
      }
   }
```

Need to be able to set the isExpanded property every time the tableview header is selected. However Im unsure how I can do this using a setter..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `feedPosts` is a computed property.

```
var feedPosts: [ExpandableItem] {
    var isOpen = true

    return [
        ExpandableItem(isExpanded: isOpen, items: posts),
        ExpandableItem(isExpanded: isOpen, items: reviews)
    ]
}
```

It means that every time you get your `ExpandableItem` array your create a new array. It means that each `isExpanded` will be `true` because `isOpen = true` is used for each new `ExpandableItem`. Even if you are able to change `isExpanded` - you will lose your progress because you don't save `ExpandableItem` array bacause it is a computed property.

The solution is: your `ExpandableItem` array should not be a computed property:

```
class FeedConstructor {

    public static var feedPosts: [ExpandableItem] = {
        var isOpen = true
        return [
            ExpandableItem(isExpanded: isOpen, items: postsIntial),
            ExpandableItem(isExpanded: isOpen, items: reviewsInitial)
        ]
    }()

    private static var postsIntial: [AddPost] {
        return [AddPost]()
    }
    private static var reviewsInitial: [ReviewPost] {
        return [ReviewPost]()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there this makes sense however with this implementation im now getting the typical error "attempt to insert row 0 into section 1, but there are only 0 rows in section 1 after the update'" Now im unsure as to if its an issue with they way my array is set up.. I might have to rethink my strategy of making an expandable tableview

Comment: Yeah, rethinking the strategy is a right way. You might also rethink the usage of static variables. Anyway, try to be careful with computed properties. You should always save the progress somewhere.

Comment: thanks for your help! that really cleared some things up for me:D